# Is there a command to move a file, and symlink it back to where it was?

Tags: symlink, fish

I often find myself wanting to move a file,
then create a symlink where it was.

In doing this by hand I tend to twist my mind.
(Esp after doing half a dozen files)

Use cases:

- Moving all my "dot files" to a folder so i can version control them
- Moving a file onto a faster disk (scratch) for High Performance Computing

If there is not a single command, 
I would appreciate a fish script. 
(fish is not a POSIX shell, does not s pport the sh language)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function lnmv
    set dest_dir $argv[1]
    set files $argv[2..-1]

    for f in $files
        set dest $dest_dir/$f
        mv -- $f $dest
        and ln -s -- $dest $f
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @oxinabox, I was thinking of making that same edit.

Comment: What do the `--` 's do?

Comment: In case one of the files begins with the `-` character, it ensures that the file is handled as a file, not as an option.